# Why does R behavior on adding to lists depend on order of assignment

Tags: r

Adding to a sublist depends on list structure.  Adding an atomic element to a sublist as the first operation does not form a sublist.

Have simple test case

```
tl <- list()
tl[['a']][['aa']] <- list(1,2,3)
tl[['a']][['bb']] <- 'b'
tl[['a']][['cc']] <- list('a','b','c','d')

bl <- list()
bl[['bb']] <- 'b'
bl[['aa']] <- list(1,2,3)
bl[['cc']] <- list('a','b','c','d')

cl <- list()
cl[['a']][['bb']] <- 'b'
cl[['a']][['aa']] <- list(1,2,3)
cl[['a']][['cc']] <- list('a','b','c','d')

dl <- list()
dl[['bb']] <- 'b'
dl[['aa']] <- list(1,2,3)
dl[['cc']] <- list('a','b','c','d')
nl <- list()
nl[['a']] <- dl
```

The lists tl, bl, and nl are as I expect.  However list cl gives the following error:  Error in cl[["b"]][["aa"]] <- list(1, 2, 3) : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace.

R is constructing different a different type of list when it is assigned an atomic sublist before attempting to assign a list() sublist.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is the default behavior of `[[<-`. This is a generic operator that does different things depending on what type of object you use it on. It's not exclusively used for lists. Consider this example

```
x <- NULL
x[["b"]] <- 'c'
# str(x)
#   Named chr "c"
#  - attr(*, "names")= chr "b"
```

Here `x` is defined as NULL. In this case, `x[["b"]]` turns `x` into a named vector (not a list). That's because R had no idea you wanted `x` to be a list so it just chose the most simple data type it could.

Assigning to a named slot and expecting a container to be automatically instantiation is called autovivification and languages like Perl really love that, it's not really a core concept in R. If you need a list where never there was a list before, be sure to explicitly created it.

```
cl <- list()
cl[['a']] <- list()
cl[['a']][['bb']] <- 'b'
cl[['a']][['aa']] <- list(1,2,3)
cl[['a']][['cc']] <- list('a','b','c','d')
```

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick!  That makes sense.  Indeed I have written tons of Perl code which uses autovivification.   I should have seen this as related to how R also flattens a single row matrix to a vector which is often a PITA.